# How to conditionally render/make visible a java fx component based on model?

Tags: java, javafx

I need to conditionally render or either make visible already rendered component based on a boolean from model. The view is defined using `.fxml` files.

Currently I do it as follows but it does not work as expected:

> ```
>  <Label text="This is random msg" visible="${controller.showingDineIn}"/>
> ```

Comment: Ideally, the model will be initiated within initialize() method of controller, either by fetching from external source or by other logic. however fxml parsing and setting the visible property of label will happen before invoking the initialize() method. I mean the model is not ready when setting the visible property. The best way is to inject label itself to the controller.

Comment: This actually works fine for me. Can you show the relevant parts of your controller?